# Nested collections, access elements type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I have two collections, the second one is inside the first one. But when I try to access the element of the second collection I get a `Type mismatch` error.

```
Sub testColls()
Dim coll1 As Collection
Dim coll2 As Collection

Set coll1 = New Collection
Set coll2 = New Collection

coll2.Add ("dog")
coll1.Add ("cat")

coll1.Add coll2

Dim temp As String
temp = coll1(1)(1)
MsgBox (temp)

End Sub
```

Why is this error? `coll1(1)` gets the second collection, `coll`(1)(1)` should give first element of the second collection.

Comment: `coll1(1)` is cat. `coll1(2)` is your `coll2`

Comment: "coll1(1) gets the second collection": No, there is not an `Item(0)` in a `Collection`. And your `Item(1)` is "cat".

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
temp = coll1(1)(1)
```

use

```
temp = coll1(2)(1)
```

Using `coll1(2)(1)` will give `dog` and `coll1(1)` will give `cat`.

To make it more readable you can use `coll1.Item(2).Item(1)` for `coll1(2)(1)` and likewise `coll1.Item(1)` for `coll1(1)`

Comment: Up-voted for pointing out that a Collection should not be used like an Array, instead Item should be used.

Comment: @AxelRichter To be more precise, accessing a Collection by using indices is not accessing it like an array. It is still accessing it like a collection. `Debug.Print SomeColl(1)(1)` is perfectly valid since the **default-member** of a `Collection` is `Item`. So `SomeColl(1)(1)` and `SomeColl.Item(1).Item(1)` are identical in their function, the second one is just easier to read (and will throw an error specifically referencing the lack of the `.Item` method on a string).