# Class constructor confusion - wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a class module with some data:

```
Private sharedFolders() As String

Public Property Let SetSharedFolders(val As String)
    Dim i As Integer

    sharedFolders = Array("folder one", "folder two")

    i = UBound(sharedFolders)

    i = UBound(sharedFolders)
    ReDim Preserve sharedFolders(i)
    sharedFolders(i) = CStr(val)

End Property

Property Get GetSharedFolders()
    GetSharedFolders = sharedFolders()
End Property
```

And I want to add something to this property from other module like this:

```
Sub PrepareData()

    Dim e
    Dim s
    Dim a(2) As String

    Set e = New Entry

    a(0) = "add one"
    a(1) = "add two"

    For Each s In a
        e.SetSharedFolders (s) 'Here comes exception
    Next

    For Each s In e.GetSharedFolders
        Debug.Print s
    Next

End Sub
```

But I receive an "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment vba" exception... Can anyone assist?

**Addendum**

Thanks to @AJD and @Freeflow to pointing out a mistake and idea to make it easier. Decided to make as like below.

Class Module:

```
Private sharedFolders As New Collection

Public Property Let SetSharedFolders(val As String)

If sharedFolders.Count = 0 Then ' if empty fill with some preset data and add new item
    sharedFolders.Add "folder 1"
    sharedFolders.Add "folder 2"
    sharedFolders.Add CStr(val)
Else
    sharedFolders.Add CStr(val)
End If

End Property 

Property Get GetSharedFolders() As Collection

Set GetSharedFolders = sharedFolders

End Property
```

and regular module:

```
Sub AddData()

Dim e As New Entry ' creating an instance of a class
Dim s As Variant ' variable to loop through collection
Dim a(1) As String 'some array with data to insert

a(0) = "add one"
a(1) = "add two"

For Each s In a
     e.SetSharedFolders = s
Next

For Each s In e.GetSharedFolders
    Debug.Print s
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe `Property Get GetSharedFolders()` needs to be like `Property Get GetSharedFolders() As String` for example

Comment: Nope, that's not the reason. I've updated the code in first message with comment where exception is thrown.

Comment: You have a property let not a sub so the syntax should be e.SetSharedFolders = s

Comment: And that's not really a property so just make it a sub...

Comment: My answer updated.

Comment: Improve naming by removing Get/Set praefix, the clue of a property is same name for Getter/Setter(Letter). Be aware of [SelfAssignedDeclaration](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/SelfAssignedDeclaration) and you can add default values at`Class_Initialize`. As Getter gets collection, Setter should set it. For adding a folder create a method`Add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I thought the problem lies in this code:

```
   i = UBound(sharedFolders)

        i = UBound(sharedFolders)
        ReDim Preserve sharedFolders(i)
        sharedFolders(i) = CStr(val)
```

`i` is set twice to the same value, and then the `sharedFolders` is `reDim`med to the same value it was before! Also, there is some trickery happening with the use of `ix` within a 0-based array.

But the problem is most likely how you have declared your variables.

```
For Each s In a
    e.SetSharedFolders (s) 'Here comes exception
Next
```

`s` is a Variant, and `a` is a Variant. At this point VBA is trying to guess how to handle a `For Each` loop with two Variants. And then the improper call is made. The correct syntax is:

```
    e.SetSharedFolders s '<-- no parenthesis
```

There are plenty of posts on StackOverflow explaining how to call routines and what the impact of the evaluating parenthesis are!

However, at this point we are only assuming it is passing in a single element of the array - it could be passing the full array itself (albeit unlikely).

And the third factor -

```
Public Property Let SetSharedFolders(val As String)
```

The parameter `val` is being passed `ByRef` and should be passed `ByVal`. This also has unintended side effects as I found out ([Type mismatch trying to set data in an object in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766436/type-mismatch-trying-to-set-data-in-an-object-in-a-collection)).

```
Public Property Let SetSharedFolders(ByVal val As String)
```

All in all you have the perfect storm of ambiguity driving to an unknown result.

The answer here is to strongly type your variables. This removes about two layers of ambiguity and areas where errors can happen. In addition, this will slightly improve code execution.

Another aspect is to understand when you should pass something `ByVal` and when to use the default (preferably explicitly) `ByRef`.

And a final gratuitous hint: Use a Collection instead of an Array. Your code you have implies a Collection will be more efficient and easier to manage.

### Addendum

(thanks to @FreeFlow):

If the OP changes the definition of `sharedfolders` to `Variant` rather than `String()` then the array statement will work as expected.

The line `e.SetSharedFolders (s)` will work fine if it is changed to `e.SetSharedFolders = s` because the method `SetSharedFolders` is a `Let Property` not a `Sub`. There are other errors but these two changes will make the code run.

Comment: If the OP changes the definition of sharedfolders to variant rather than string then the array statement will work as expected.   The line 'e.SetSharedFolders (s)' will work fine if it is changed to e.SetSharedFolders =(s) because the Method SetSharedFolders is a let property not a sub.  There are other errors but these two changes will make the code run.

Comment: @Freeflow: Yes, obvious now that you point that out! I have updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks AJD! I've missed exactly this thing: `The line 'e.SetSharedFolders (s)' will work fine if it is changed to e.SetSharedFolders =(s) because the Method SetSharedFolders is a let property not a sub."`

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak be careful with [parentheses in procedure calls](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/24427/byref)